# installing a console application as a windows service in windows server 2003

Tags: c#

This might be a basic question so apologies in advance.

I have a console application that I want to test on a windows server 2003.

I built the application on Release mode in C# with 4.0 framework, and have taken the contents of the bin folder and pasted to a folder on windows server 2003 directory.

When I run the exe I get the following error:
"Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A windows service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, ...."

Now I want to install this console app using the installutil.exe as  a service.

Can anyone please show me how.

Thank you.

Comment: So what happened when you ran InstallUtil?

Comment: I got the Installed confirmation message. But I cannot see my service  in Component Services.

Comment: You will not see your service in Component Services, rather in just `Services`. Start->Run-> Type Services.msc-> Press Enter. Thats where your service should be, if installed correctly.

Comment: What happens when you run your app from the console? If it runs and quits right away, the same thing will happen when you install it as a service. The service will start and then immediately stop, because the app finished. It won't stay running just because you installed it as a service.

Comment: @Abhinav: I did look at Services.msc and couldn't locate my service. I looked at the log file and it mentions the following: "No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the <FilePath>". My app was built as a console application not a windows service app.

Comment: You can create a service from any .exe using the `sc` commandline tool.

Answer (score 5):

You change Main method;

```
static partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsService();
    }

    static void RunAsService()
    {
        ServiceBase[] servicesToRun;
        servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MainService() };
        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
}
```

And you create new Windows Service(MainService) and Installer Class(MyServiceInstaller);

MainService.cs;

```
partial class MainService : ServiceBase
{
    public MainService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        base.OnShutdown();
    }
}
```

MyServiceInstaller.cs;

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class SocketServiceInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;
    private ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller;

    public SocketServiceInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "My Service Name";

        var serviceDescription = "This my service";

        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        Installers.Add(processInstaller);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to install this console app using the installutil.exe as a service.

You need to convert it to a Windows Service application instead of a console application.  See the [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) on MSDN for details.

The other option would be to use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to schedule the system to run your Console Application.  This can behave very similarly to a service without actually creating a service, as you can schedule the application to run on any schedule you choose.

Comment: I guess he already has a service or he would not get that error message in the first place.